# Block pop-ups coming from iframe?

Tags: video, iframe, embed, sandbox

how do I block pop-ups coming from embed video iframe?
Some have too many popups before you can play the video.
I'm using WP.

Sandbox won't work because then the video does not even display, I assume they have something to prevent the use of sandbox protections, or it just does not apply to these videos.

Can't find any instance of my situation online or maybe people just don't want to talk openly about embedding video content from other then social media.